# Gear slipping in gear 24

Tags: gears, derailleur, cassette

I use my bike everyday to commute and recently I've noticed that when in gear 24 my bike seems to slip from time to time as though the chain has "lost the gear" and then finds it again.

I haven't changed gear and when I change down into gear 23 the problem goes away. I'm thinking it must be a problem with my cassette/derailleur but I'm not sure what the problem would be. I'm kind of a novice when it comes to bike maintenance but I was wondering whether anybody could tell me what I should do?

Comment: You might need to adjust the derailleur, but you might need a new chain and possbily a new cassette (rear gears).  You might want to get it looked at, but you can measure chain wear

Comment: We don't generally refer to gears by numbers.  Instead, its more like   46/14 where the first number is the number of teeth on the front chainring, and the second number is the number of teeth on the rear cassette cog, both where the chain is sitting.   You say gear 24, so its likely to be the biggest chainring, and the smallest cog on the cassette.

Comment: You need to tell us which cog and which chainring.  And how many cogs and chainrings do you have?

Comment: (But likely the cable just needs to be adjusted slightly.  If you are mechanically inclined you can figure it out or study the tutorials on the Park Tool website.  Otherwise take it to a bike shop for a "tuneup".)

Comment: If it's the extreme gear it could well be the limit screw instead. And the smallest cog on the cassette usually wears fastest, so it may be a sign that your cassette is worn out.

Comment: Voted to close with "Unclear what you're asking", since you haven't replied to any of our questions.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, it just needed a slight adjustment to the cable, it wasn't totally in line with the gear. That might be your issue as well, be careful adjusting though, I adjusted too much the first time and the chain came off altogether.

Answer (score 0):

This was a common problem for young riders in the 'good old days' when chains and 'freewheels' (the threaded type, no replaced by the cassette type) were begged, borrowed or taken from the bins of bike shops and mixed with different chains.

The cranks would suddenly 'jump', as if the chain was riding up over a sprocket, which was what was in fact happening. On occasions, this was caused by a stiff link, usually where the rivet had been punched in with a hammer and punch (we're talking schoolboys here!), or a small section of different chain had been inserted into another.

In truth, the answer was usually that the freewheel and chain had to be replaced or just continue to suffer the jumping!